# Excel How To Match Duplicates Entries Between 2 Columns And Return The Matches In 3rd

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

Hi everyone here's the situation take this example:

Column

```
User Date           
1     4           
2     BLANK           
4     2           
BLANK 1
```

Ideally I get column C to match 1/1, 4/4, and 2/2 any other matches that might come up later (2000 columns in this file). How can I do this?

Comment: Automated in the sense the formula should generate the matches. Unless your way can search through 2000 columns.

Comment: Sorry Brandon, I removed my initial comment as I had something else in mind. Hopefully my suggested solution works out for you.

Comment: Please add your expected outcome to the test data above.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  1) You have 2 columns, User and Date.  What would be in those two columns that would match?  2) You have some placeholders in the example.  User value 1 matches Date value 4, etc.  What actually goes in column 3 and where?  Please give an example of what the output should look like.

Comment: Good question. The actual answer is more messy. Should I repost or reformat?

Comment: @Brandon, just edit the question as needed.  BTW, if you "address" comments to a specific user with @, like I did here, they will get a notification.  Otherwise nobody will be aware of your comment unless they happen to stumble across it.

Answer (score 0):

In column 3 cells: `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,B1), B1 & "/" & B1, IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1), A1 & "/" & A1, ""))`

This is what's happening:
If Column A contains B1, then write B1/B1
If it did not contain B1, then check if column B contains A1
If Column B contained A1, then write A1/A1
Else don't write anything because we couldnt match the value from either column on this row.

My results using the formula above:

```
A      B      C
3      2      3/3
4      5      5/5
5      3      3/3
6      6      6/6
7      8      7/7
       3      3/3
       3      3/3
3      7      7/7
a      a      a/a
88     88     88/88
hi     asdf   hi/hi
bb     bb     bb/bb
ab     ab     ab/ab
ab            ab/ab
cd            cd/cd
       cd     cd/cd
       hi     hi/hi
```

Comment: Hi is there a way to make it so if anything from A matches anything in B?

Comment: just updated with what I think will do you good. At least, it seems to work on my screen.

Comment: Hey sorry, not sure it worked, it's not grabbing duplicates.

Comment: If I could thank you a million times, I would. You're amazing. I'll tweak it a little but thanks!

Comment: Ok, if this last edit does not work, I'll pull out of here and let someone else answer.

Comment: I take it that update #2 worked. So I'll remove the bad stuff from my answer.

Comment: Still working on it. It seems to leave a lot of spaces and is an endless loop of names.